# Is necessary to recreate MTLBuffer, MTLTexture or other metal resources when the app is brought to foreground?

Tags: ios, metal, mtlbuffer

I'm refactoring the render layer of cocos2d-x, and the new engine will use Metal on `iOS`. In the original version, cocos2dx would recreate all buffers and textures when the app was brought to  foreground after a long time stayed in the background.

I'm a newbie with Metal, and my question is: Is it necessary to recreate the MTLBuffer, MTLTexture and other Metal resources as GLES?

Answer (score 5):

It's not necessary to recreate Metal resources when an app returns to being active from being in a background state.

On the other hand, since textures and buffers can be large, and because they reside in system memory for the duration of their lifetime (iOS has a unified memory architecture and lacks a paging system), you may want to free some or all of your Metal resources when *entering* a background state to reduce the likelihood that your app gets terminated when another app needs the memory it is using. In that case, you'd recreate those resources if/when your app returns from the background state.

Comment: Thanks a million.